# Wicket Ajax Callback URL invalid after navigating back

Tags: java, ajax, callback, wicket

I'm using Wicket 6.xx.
The problem: Given `Panel` with an `AbstractAjaxBehavior`:

```
public class Foo extends Panel {

    private AbstractAjaxBehavior cbUrl;

    public Foo(String id) {
        super(id);

        cbUrl = new AbstractAjaxBehavior() {
            //... onRequest Override with JSON body
        }

        add(cbUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);

        response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("executeSomeCode('" + 
                             cbUrl.getCallbackUrl().toString() + "');"));
    }
}
```

On initial pageload, everything works fine as intended. But when navigated to another page using a `Link` and coming back using the browsers *back* button, the callback url becomes invalid and returns the pages html code instead of the JSON.

Am i missing some important step in the Ajax configuration?

Comment: Try with latest 6.x.0 and report back with a quickstart if the problem persists.

Comment: I'M using 6.14.0. Whsat do you mean with quickstart?

Comment: The quickstart is a minimal test project to reproduce the problem. See http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html Sven is one of the Wicket developers so he probably thinks this is a Wicket bug.

Comment: Eventually i solved the problem: after navigating back the persistence manager wasn't available any more and therefore no data were available.